# I made several divs using JS, however only one of them react to DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, dom, setattribute

I want to change the color of all my divs that I created with Javascript. My code should have given them all the same class name and id name, but only one of them changes color or interacts with my DOM manipulation. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong, or how I can fix it?

```
function makeRows(rows, cols){
for (let i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++){
  let container= document.getElementById("container");
 let cell= document.createElement("div");
  cell.innerText = (i + 1);
  cell.setAttribute('id','box');
  container.appendChild(cell).className = "gridBox"; 
}
};

makeRows(16,16);

//events

const box= document.getElementById('box');
document.getElementById('box').setAttribute("style", "background-color:red;");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create multiple div's you have to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all elements with the class `.box`

```
document.querySelectorAll('.box').forEach(box => {
   box.setAttribute("style", "background-color:red;");
});
```